# "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" occurs while running unit test cases

Tags: unit-testing, exception

I have created a custom control and maintains nearly 2000 unit testcases for the control.
The objects used in the each test cases were disposed properly.

The below exceptions occurs randomly while running the unit test cases.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : A device attached to the system is not functioning
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)


System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Error creating window handle.
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
```

I can't able figure out the root cause for these exceptions.